# expectation of Gamma distribution help

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gamma-function, parameter-estimation

If x∼Gamma(1,λ) how would i find the expected value E(e^bx) where b=aλ

I'm kinda stuck as to how to approach the question. Some help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: You basically want to find the characteristic function of the Gamma distribution. Except, with your parameters $(1,\lambda)$, the density is just $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ which should be very easy to calculate expectations with.

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for responding to my post. I got to the part where E(X) =integral of e^aλx * λe^−λx * dx. Problem is i'm not too sure how exactly I can calculate from here. If you dont mind answering a little bit more in terms of how it will simplify down to, i'll learn a lot from it

Comment: try integration by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have $X\sim \mathcal{Gamma}(1,\lambda)$, which means that pdf of $X$ looks like
$$w_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
And you need to find $\mathrm{E}\{e^{a\lambda X}\}$.
Then
$$\mathrm{E}\{e^{a\lambda X}\}=\int_0^\infty e^{a\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \;\mathrm dx=\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-x \lambda (1-a) } \;\mathrm dx$$
Changing the variable to $t=\lambda (1-a)x$ one can get
$$\mathrm{E}\{e^{a\lambda X}\}=\frac{1}{1-a}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\;\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{1-a}$$ if $\Re{(a)}<1$.

If $a\in\mathbb{C}$ then 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{E}\{e^{a\lambda X}\}=\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{\mathrm i \Im{(a)}\lambda x}e^{\Re{(a)}\lambda x}e^{-\lambda x} \;\mathrm dx=
\lambda\int_0^\infty \cos(\underbrace{\Im{(a)}\lambda}_{\omega} x)e^{-\overbrace{(1-\Re{(a)})\lambda}^p x} \;\mathrm dx&+&\\ 
+\lambda\int_0^\infty \sin(\underbrace{\Im{(a)}\lambda}_{\omega} x)e^{-\overbrace{(1-\Re{(a)})\lambda}^p x} \;\mathrm dx
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which can be treated as the unilateral Laplace transforms of $\sin(\omega x)$ and $\cos(\omega x)$.
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{ \sin(\omega x) \right\}={ \omega \over s^2 + \omega^2  },  \qquad \mathcal{L}\left\{ \cos(\omega x) \right\}={ s\over s^2 + \omega^2  } $$
After simplifications one can get $\mathrm{E}\{e^{a\lambda X}\}=\frac{1}{1-\left(\Re{(a)}+\mathrm i\Im{(a)}\right)}$ if $\Re{(a)}<1$.

Comment: Thank you very much Caran, would you care to have a look at this next question of mine? [link to the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511874/expected-value-for-gamma-and-uniform-distributionrepeat)

Comment: (Changed some x to X.) The last argument does not apply if $\Im a\ne0$, fortunately finding a primitive does the job.

Comment: The substitution is not correct: here $t$ does not depend on $x$ and some lambdas are missing.

Comment: @Did thanks, now it is better.

Comment: Hmmm... I was suggesting that, since $(\mathrm e^{zx})'=z\mathrm e^{zx}$ on $x$ in $\mathbb R$ for **every** complex number $z$, the integral of $x\to\mathrm e^{zx}$ on $(0,+\infty)$ is $z^{-1}\left[\mathrm e^{zx}\right]_{x=0}^{x=+\infty}=-z^{-1}$ for every $z$ such that $\mathrm e^{zx}\to0$ when $x\to+\infty$, that is, every $z$ such that $\Re(z)\lt0$. (No need to decompose the exponential into its cosine and sine parts and to appeal to Laplace transform, just use the complex exponential as it is.)